# Display certain items of a WordPress menu

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

I generate a menu in Wordpress that has three layers. I do that with the code:

```
wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'SecondaryNavigation'));
```

Wordpress generates a menu like this:

```
<div class="menu-mainnavigation_de-container">
<ul id="menu-mainnavigation_de" class="SecondaryNavigation">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-39">
        <a href="http://localhost/fecheriye/de/einfuehrung/">Home</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-44" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-44"><a href="http://localhost/fecheriye/de/einfuehrung/">Einführung</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-43" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-43"><a href="http://localhost/fecheriye/de/aktuelles/">Aktuelles</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-30 current_page_item current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-40">
        <a href="http://localhost/fecheriye/de/beschreibung/">Der Tell</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-42" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-30 current_page_item menu-item-42"><a href="http://localhost/fecheriye/de/beschreibung/">Beschreibung</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-41" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-41"><a href="http://localhost/fecheriye/de/topographie/">Topographie</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-51">
        <a href="http://localhost/fecheriye/de/forschungsgeschichte/">Forschung</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-53" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-53"><a href="http://localhost/fecheriye/de/forschungsgeschichte/">Forschungsgeschichte</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-52" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-52"><a href="http://localhost/fecheriye/de/forschungsprobleme/">Forschungsprobleme</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-65">
        <a href="http://localhost/fecheriye/de/kampagnen/">Kampagnen</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-64" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-64">
                <a href="http://localhost/fecheriye/de/ausgrabung-2010/">Ausgrabung 2010</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-63" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-63"><a href="http://localhost/fecheriye/de/grabungsstelle-c-haus-i-sq-6644-5-6744-6-6844-6/">Grabungsstelle C &#8211; Haus I (Sq. 6644-5, 6744-6 &#038; 6844-6)</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have to divide the menu into two menues: In the header on the top, only the first layer of the menu is visible. This is very easy with the depth-call of wp_nav_menu and works just fine.
In the Sidebar I want to display the corresponding second and third level (everything under the class .sub-menu) of the menu, depending what was selected in the header. I tried to do this via CSS with the two simple lines:

```
.SecondaryNavigation {
  display: none;
  }

.SecondaryNavigation .current-menu-ancestor .sub-menu {
  display: block;
  }
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. How can I display only the second and third level of my menu, depending on what was selected in the primary level? Wordpress assigns the corresponding classes, like .current-menu-ancestor or .sub-menu, so it must be possible in some way, right?

Thanks for your help!
All the best
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

I would simply create the secondary menus and then list on the pages accordingly, which will be quite simple and effective.

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: You mean to create each sub-menu separately? That would be possible of course, but quite a mess, the more that this website will be in three languages and therefore that would mean a lot of sub-menus....